# Is there any way to set processor affinity of a powershell script before execution?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, processor, affinity

There are lots of examples showing the use of `Get-Process myprocess` to change the processor affinity, and some examples using `Get-WMIObject`; but these won't work for my use. I want to set processor affinity of my script as it executes. Is there a way to declare processor affinity when calling powershell.exe, or from within the script itself?

The exe I'm calling is in cygwin; which appears to change the affinity after being started with `cmd.exe /c start <command> /affinity 16`

Comment: starting powershell from a cmd using `start.exe /affinity` ?

Comment: That partially works; however, the exe must be executed via cygwin. It looks like this is changing the affinity to use all CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me, but I haven't tested it.  It seems to update what Task Manager sees, however.

```
$thisProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess();
$thisProcess.ProcessorAffinity = 0x1;
```

`ProcessorAffinity` is a bitmask, so `0x1` is core 1, `0x2` is core 2, `0x4` is core 3, `0x8` is core 4, and so on.  If you want to set cores 1-4, it's `0xF`, cores 1-9, `0x1FF`, etc.  I don't think there's any magic value to set it back to "All".

You could also use `Get-Process -Id $pid`, since `$pid` is an automatic variable with the current process' PID.

Comment: You can do the same thing with Get-Process. If you want to set it back to "ALL", you can run this to get the numerical value to use for ProcessorAffinity:

`[convert]::ToInt32($("1" * $(gwmi win32_processor | Select -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores | Measure-Object -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum)),2)`

Comment: @EGr To cater for hyperthreading `NumberOfLogicalProcessors`  needs to be used provided it is greater than `NumberOfCores`, see [Win32_Processor Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Using binary numbers directly e.g. `0b11` can be clearer than hex.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli That's true, but binary integer notation is not supported by Windows Powershell v5.1 and earlier.